# Link in main menu does not point to specified path

Tags: routes, navigation

I'm trying to add a link to my site's about page to the main menu as an "About" link. I have configured it in the following manner:

```
Menu link title: About
Path: node/2
Description: (none)
Enabled: selected
Show as expanded: deselected
Parent link: Main menu
Weight: 1
```

I do get an "About" link created in the main menu, but this points to `http://about/`
and not to `http://{sitename}/node/2`. I know that I can add the full URL and adding the full URL does work, however, I'm interested to this with relative paths.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the $base_url variable in your settings file. Open settings.php, usually sites/default/settings.php, and search for '$base_url', there are instructions within the comments about how to set it correctly.